# Can't deploy application on WebSphere Application Server v8.5 [RAD IDE]

Tags: java, eclipse, websphere, ibm-rad

I'm using the Rational Application Developer IDE (RAD, which is a modification of eclipse) to modify an existing application. The problem is that I can't deploy the application on WebSphere Application Server v8.5, I actually get a french error message which translates to "Impossible to find the valid parent module to add to the server" and the next and finish buttons are disabled as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

I have done some research I found out that it could be due to the fact that an EAR project doesn't exist but it is actually the case and I'm wondering if there is a configuration tweak to perfom to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the version of WebSphere Application Server that you are using and what is the EAR facet version of the EAR project?  You may get that error because the EAR facet version is not supported by the server.